# can't create Pool on Raydium

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust

I'm facing issues creating a pool on Raydium. I make a market ID and then want to create a pool with my token paired with USDC(myToken/USDC), it shows an error that the freeze authority can't be enabled. Their documentation also mentions that

- Pool creation requires the base token to have freeze authority disabled.  *

it's possible to change the minting token's freeze authority from enabled to disabled. If this is possible, could you please guide me on how to make this change? I've checked the Solana cookbook link, but it seems to focus on minting, which may not be directly related to my issue.

- https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#what-do-i-need-to-get-started-with-spl-tokens *

Comment: I'm using the SetAuthority method to freeze the authority but I get the following error: 'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]', 'Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority', 'Program log: Error: Account does not support specified authority type', 'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2653 of 200000 compute units', 'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0xf' Can you please help me to understand the issue???
I'm lost with this issue !

Comment: Hi @David,
This error mean Account does not support specified authority type that your are using the wrong accounts for change the authority, you can check https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-set-authority-on-token-accounts-or-mints for further check or create the new issue and let me know. I'll try to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the freeze authority programmatically using "null" and setting the AuthorityType to FreezeAccount. Check the snippet and link as reference:

```
 {
    let txhash = await setAuthority(
      connection, // connection
      feePayer, // payer
      mintPubkey, // mint account || token account
      authorityKeypair, // Keypair of the current authority
      AuthorityType.FreezeAccount, // authority type
      null // you pass `null` to disable a freeze authority
    );
    console.log(`txhash: ${txhash}`);
  }
```

https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-set-authority-on-token-accounts-or-mints
NOTE: When you disable it you can't turn it on again